# String split formatting in python 3

Tags: python, formatting, newline

I'm trying to format this string below where one row contains five words. However, I keep getting this as the output:

> I love cookies yes I do Let s see a dog

First, I am not getting 5 words in one line, but instead, everything in one line.

Second, why does the "Let's" get split? I thought in splitting the string using "words", it will only split if there was a space in between?

Suggestions?

```
string = """I love cookies. yes I do. Let's see a dog."""


# split string
words = re.split('\W+',string)

words = [i for i in words if i != '']


counter = 0
output=''
for i in words:
    if counter == 0:
        output +="{0:>15s}".format(i)

# if counter == 5, new row
    elif counter % 5 == 0:
       output += '\n'
       output += "{0:>15s}".format(i)

    else:
       output += "{0:>15s}".format(i)

    # Increase the counter by 1
    counter += 1

print(output)
```

Comment: I forgot to copy that here. Just did it.

Comment: Thanks! This post makes more sense now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As a start, don't call a variable "string" since it shadows the [module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#module-string) with the same name

Secondly, use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to do your word-splitting

```
>>> s = """I love cookies. yes I do. Let's see a dog."""
>>> s.split()
['I', 'love', 'cookies.', 'yes', 'I', 'do.', "Let's", 'see', 'a', 'dog.']
```

From [re-module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> > > \W
> > >       Matches any character which is not a Unicode word character. This is the opposite of \w. If the ASCII flag is used this becomes the equivalent of [^a-zA-Z0-9_] (but the flag affects the entire regular expression, so in such cases using an explicit [^a-zA-Z0-9_] may be a better choice).

Since the `'` is not listed in the above, the regexp used splits the "Let's" string into two parts:

```
>>> words = re.split('\W+', s)
>>> words
['I', 'love', 'cookies', 'yes', 'I', 'do', 'Let', 's', 'see', 'a', 'dog', '']
```

This is the output I get using the strip()-approach above:

```
$ ./sp3.py 
              I           love       cookies.            yes              I
            do.          Let's            see              a           dog.
```

The code could probably be simplified to this since `counter==0` and the else-clause does the same thing. I through in an [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) there as well to get rid of the counter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

s = """I love cookies. yes I do. Let's see a dog."""
words = s.split()

output = ''
for n, i in enumerate(words):
    if n % 5 == 0:
        output += '\n'
    output += "{0:>15s}".format(i)
print(output)
```

Comment: Anymore insight on to why it won't format with one 5 words per row? Thanks

Comment: @user1631819 - see my ouput, looks ok to me. Do you agree?

Comment: @fredrickpihl You mean at a words.strip() before the loop?

Comment: @user1631819 - posted complete code (somewhat simplified), please have a look

Comment: It does look much better. I was trying to look at it through local host as an HTML output, so I kept on getting the one line. But does work through terminal .

Answer (score 1):

```
words = string.split()
while (len(words))
     for word in words[:5]
          print(word, end=" ")
     print()
     words = words[5:]
```

That's the basic concept, split it using the split() method

Then slice it using slice notation to get the first 5 words

Then slice off the first 5 words, and loop again

Comment: split(), well, splits on whitespace per default, no need for the `(" ")` part

Comment: @stephan I tried you suggestion, as I did this: `while i < len(words):
     print (words[:5] '\n')
     words = words[5:]`I want a newline for every row, so I included '/n'. but now I'm getting a error at the new line. suggestions? thanks

Comment: not sure why you changed the while loop, it works like it is.  I'll update my answer to print with proper formatting since it seems like you like mine